# How to implement buttons inside a Rowlist or ZoomRowlist in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

How to implement 2 buttons as shown in the image so that when we reaches that row, the focus can be brought to that buttons and move between them also. All these within a Rowlist or ZoomRowlist. I have tried ZoomRowlist for this, but I could only add a banner.[see this image for the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V17UB.jpg)

I have tried ZoomRowlist for this, but I could only add a banner

Comment: Unfortunately, RowLists (and ArrayGrids in general) are not designed with that in mind.


There are however workarounds for this limitation, such as


 - communicating with the items via their ContentNodes. for instance, having a field `keyPressed` that, in your case, can accept the values `left` / `right` and making the item respond to that field change (this will trigger a `itemContent` update). The parent list will also need to check if the item will "handle" that key press so that the parents onKeyEvent returns true so it won't natively navigate to the same item.

Comment: - alternatively, make the focused item expose itself to the parent - since RowList items can access their parent RowList via `m.top.getParent()` you can do something like `m.top.getParent().focusedItem = m.top` (focusedItem can be a custom node field) and proceed with the key handling process on as explained above. -

These clearly are not optimal implementations so I am not posting as an answer but they will get your task done.

Comment: @RúbenFreitas, Thanks for the suggestion. let me try that.